# Joining two id's two single table

Tags: mysql

I have this MySql query here:

```
    SELECT 
    tbl_News.NewsId, 
    tbl_News.UserId, 
    tbl_News.NewsTitle, 
    tbl_News.NewsText, 
    tbl_News.NewsDateTime,
    tbl_News.NewsUpdatedDateTime,
    tbl_News.IsDisabled, tbl_Users.UserId,
    tbl_Users.UserId AS CreatedByUserId,
    tbl_Users.UserId AS UpdatedByUserId,
    tbl_Users.Username As CreatedByUsername,
    tbl_Users.Username as UpdatedByUsername

FROM tbl_News 
INNER JOIN tbl_Users ON tbl_News.UserId = tbl_Users.UserId
AND tbl_News.UpdatedByUserId = tbl_Users.UserId
```

I am trying to join this to my tbl_Users table, I have used UserId twice and given them a different alias, I am not trying to do an inner join on the two labels using the alias name. However I am not having any success and not sure if what I am doing is the correct way to do it. Any help / advise on this would be great

The problem I am having is I need to return the username for who created it and who updated it, since they will be two different ids

Comment: "Not having any success" ... can you give a specific error or issue you are having?

Comment: Well I removed the [ ] and it solved the syntax error, but now it just runs and nothing happens, returns no data

Comment: Are you sure that you have data in the joining condition ?

Comment: Yes, I have about 6 rows in each

Comment: Hmm you need to join the user table 2 times with 2 different alias to get the usernames. If you create a fiddle in http://sqlfiddle.com with some data we can see whats going on.

Comment: Why would `tbl_News` have both a UserId and an UpdatedByUserId that point to the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting both created user and updated user details from the same table user using JOIN, which will not work. You need to join the user table 2 times something as

```
SELECT 
n.NewsId, 
n.UserId, 
n.NewsTitle, 
n.NewsText, 
n.NewsDateTime,
n.NewsUpdatedDateTime,
n.IsDisabled, 
n.UserId AS CreatedByUserId,
n.UpdatedByUserId AS UpdatedByUserId,
u1.Username As CreatedByUsername,
u2.Username as UpdatedByUsername
FROM tbl_News n
JOIN tbl_Users u1 ON u1.UserId = n.UserId 
join tbl_Users u2 on u2.UserId = n.UpdatedByUserId
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two joins, assuming `UserId` and `UpdatedByUserId` are *not the same thing*:

```
SELECT 
    tbl_News.NewsId, 
    tbl_News.UserId, 
    tbl_News.NewsTitle, 
    tbl_News.NewsText, 
    tbl_News.NewsDateTime,
    tbl_News.NewsUpdatedDateTime,
    tbl_News.IsDisabled, tbl_Users.UserId,
    u1.UserId AS CreatedByUserId,
    u2.UserId AS UpdatedByUserId,
    u1.Username As CreatedByUsername,
    u2.Username as UpdatedByUsername

FROM tbl_News 
INNER JOIN tbl_Users u1 ON 
    tbl_News.UserId = u1.UserId
INNER JOIN tbl_Users u2 ON
    tbl_News.UpdatedByUserId = u2.UserId
```

What you're doing: Grabbing all of the rows from `tbl_News`, and then joining that to `tbl_users` where `tbl_Users.UserId` is equal to *both* `tbl_News.UserId` and `tbl_News.UpdatedByUserId`. This seems...peculiar. Why even include both in the join condition?

What you're trying to do: Grab all of the rows for `tbl_News`, and then get the usernames of the users who created said news item and updated said news item. This requires *two joins*. You can join a table more than once--it's okay. In this case, `tbl_Users` takes on a different context, so you get the users who created the news in `u1`, and then you get the users who updated the news in `u2`.